# Assign Json object to string array

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I have a json string as shown below

```
[{"question":"Test Queston 1 ?","option1":null,},{"question":"Test Question 2 ?","option1":null}]
```

I want to assign the "question" objects to  String [] questions_list. How can I iterate through this json objects?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSON.org Java Library for this. Just add the library to your project. If you are using Maven you can add the dependency from here: [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810).
The source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java). The docs can be found [here.](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html)

Then you can do something like this:

```
JSONArray questionsArray = new JSONArray("[{"question":"Test Queston 1 ?","option1":null,},{"question":"Test Question 2 ?","option1":null}]");
for (int i = 0; i < questionsArray.length();, i++){
    JSONObject questionJSON = questionsArray.get(i);
    String questionName = questionJSON.get("question");
    String option1 = question.JSON.get("option1");
    //And so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you want to convert your JSON to java array.

Below is very basic test which I have wrote:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.json.*;


public class JsonTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String s="[{\"year\":\"2015\",\"org\":\"1\",\"sub_org\":\"2\",\"sub_org_amt\":\"1\"}," +
                "{\"year\":\"2016\",\"org\":\"2\",\"sub_org\":\"3\",\"sub_org_amt\":\"1\"}]";
        StringReader reader=new StringReader(s);
        JsonReader r=Json.createReader(reader);             

        JsonArray a=r.readArray();
        String ar[]=new String[a.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){

            ar[i]=a.getJsonObject(i).toString();

           System.out.println(ar[i]);
        }
        r.close();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{"year":"2015","org":"1","sub_org":"2","sub_org_amt":"1"}
{"year":"2016","org":"2","sub_org":"3","sub_org_amt":"1"}
```